# Record in TwiML is skipped

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

The Record verb in TwiML is not working for me. It just skips Record and goes on to the next verb.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
  <Say>Hello.</Say>
  <Say voice="woman">What is truth?</Say>
  <Record action="http://twilio.example.com/test1a/not%20known" maxLength="60" method="GET" />
</Response>
```

Any ideas as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio Support advised the answer for my case: the Content-Type in the TwiML needs to be set to text/html but I had defaulted to text/plain. Once I explicitly set the content type header, it worked.

Comment: Do we need to set the Content-Type in the TwiML explictly? I thought this was set automatically for us if we are using TwiML. Is that not the case? How to set the Content-Type? Can you please give me an example. Thanks

Comment: It depends on how you are generating the file. I am using a web framework that defaults to text/plain.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Twilio Evangelist here.

I just tried this using [TwimlBin](http://twimlbin.com) and number on my account and everything seems to be okay.

I recommend you check [your logs](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/calls) and use the Request Inspector to see what is happening. If you can't find anything apparently wrong, then you may want to email your account SID to help@twilio.com so Twilio Support can look into it for you.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

But I thought if we TwiML then the Content-Type is automatically set for us and we don't need to explicitly set it. Did that change now?